# How can I allow specific addresses to send email?

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have a network split into two parts - one for office and server computers, and one for computers that manage scientific instruments. The instrument computers are running on the vendor's patch schedule, meaning some of them were just upgraded from windows XP, so we keep them relatively isolated from the office machines.

This has worked relatively well, but some of the instrument machines need to be able to send email via our server running postfix. I've been able to get them sending the mail by setting `mynetworks_style` to `class`, and opening up our whole block to send email. I'd like to get it so that all application servers, desktops, etc in the office subnet can still use the server to send mail, but a whitelist on the instrument subnet can send mail. Can that be configured through `mynetworks`, or does it require more configuration?

Comment: Is there two subnets with a router or only one subnet with human splitting ?

Comment: Two subnets with a router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set individual IPs in your mynetworks file, just use the /32 netmask, like this:

`192.168.1.1/32 192.168.1.4/32 192.168.1.199/32`

If you'd like a bit more security, I'd set up SASL authentication on your office machines, configure them up to use SASL authentication, then include a mynetworks file with the IPs of just the scientific machines. If you allow SASL_authenticated, then mynetworks, you will have both security for the office machines, and something functional for the scientific ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that on postfix with mynetworks, on your router if you open the port 25 to postfix server from each scientific IP machine, and it should work.